# How to authentication two different azure application?

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, azure-active-directory

I have two Azure Web applications with frontend and backend api that use Azure Active Directory. These apps short single sign-on, once the user logs in the frontend will generate the access token using the client ID and get redirected to the homepage of the app, the same token is then passed to the API on the BE whenever needed. This works without issue however now I would like to have the following.

User 1 sign's into Application 1 and gets the necessary token and then there is a link to application 2 on the app 1 homepage. Currently, when the user clicks the link to application two they need to follow the login process once again. I would like to have the user sign in seamlessly, either using the same access token ( not sure if this is possible since the token would be generated with app1 client ID which is different than app2 client ID/token)
or if there is another way of achieving this ?

Comment: Sounds like you might potentially want only 1 application, and multiple clients/policies for it

Comment: Yeah, the only way to make it work completely seamless is to use a single application. However that will have significant implications on security and architecture that you should evaluate.

Comment: @Adam - Can you add more detail what do you mean multiple clients ?

Comment: I (currently) like to think of an application as a bunch of users. You can have multiple front ends for this application (bunch of users) to log in to - these will be implemented using clients for this single application. Applications can be configured to have unique flows/login experiences (via a mechanism I think azure calls "policies"), that clients can use but if they're all the same application (bunch of users) then SSO works out of the box. My gut tells me, you only really have 1 application, but you've separated it into 2 based on your implementations (I could be wrong)

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created a `BackEnd` App and Exposed an API, added `FrontEnd` Application as Authorized:

[image]

Now, in the `FrontEnd` Application I added API permissions like below:

[image]

> When the user clicks the link to application two they need to follow the login process once again. I would like to have the user sign in seamlessly, either using the same access token or if there is another way of achieving this?

To avoid user to login twice, you can use the scope as
`api://BackEndAPI/test.read User.Read`.

For **sample**, I used the below endpoint to authorize users:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/3f5c7a77-062d-426c-8582-1238b1a77336/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=844d1e94-02d2-4cf0-ba7c-6c9a001ed20f
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://e9be528a-07b1-4894-bb20-482992f782e3/test.read User.Read
&state=12345
```

[image]

***Otherwise***, you can make use of  [**On-Behalf Flow**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#example) like below:

I generated access token by using **Authorization code flow** by using below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id: <FrontEnd_app_ID>
grant_type:authorization_code
scope: api://<API_app_ID>/test.read
code: code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
client_secret: <secret>
```

[image]

Now pass the above token in assertion like below and access token will be generated using OBO flow successfully:

```http
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id: <BackEnd_app_ID>
client_secret: <BackEnd_app_secret>
scope: api://<BackEnd_app_ID>/test.read
grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion: <paste_token_from_above_request>
requested_token_use: on_behalf_of
```

[image]

> I agree with @*Adam*, if still the issue persists create a single application and try.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I managed to solve it by adding some parameters to the init URL link to Azure:
Profile & offline_access (scopes) and query (response mode).

https://XXX.XXX.co.il/testb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_test/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=XXX&scope=**offline_access%20openid%20profile**&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FXXX.co.il%2FSSOCallback&**response_mode=query**&response_type=code

Hope it helps..